# Yii - validate custom field

Tags: validation, yii, model, relation

I use model which not contain attribute 'countries' because I'm saving it in relations-model via many-to-many relation. When I'm creating form in view I use multiple select for custom field 'countries'. How can I validate it from model on `$model->validate()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
// protected/extensions/validators/CountryValidator.php
class CountryValidator extends CValidator
{

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function validateAttribute($object, $attribute)
{
    /* @var $object CFormModel */
    // for example check exist countryId in db or no
    // you can use any other logic
    $country = Country::model()->findByPk($object->$attribute);
    if (null != $country) {
        $object->addError($attribute, 'country not found');
    }
}
...

// in your model
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('countryId', 'ext.validators.CountryValidator'),
         ...

// in config
'import' => array(
    'ext.validators.*',
    ...
```

How to use:

```
$yourModel = new YourModel();
$yourModel->countryId = -1;
$yourModel->validate();
print_r($yourModel->getErrors()); die();
```